# Terminal not accepting commands

Tags: terminal

```
    Last login: Fri Sep 27 15:42:55 on ttys000
    You have mail.
    -bash: EO: command not found
    -bash: cl: command not found
    -bash: cl: command not found
    -bash(7167,0x10a4bf5c0) malloc: can't allocate region
    *** mach_vm_map(size=18446744071689805824) failed (error code=3)
    -bash(7167,0x10a4bf5c0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
    -bash: xrealloc: cannot allocate 18446744071689803274 bytes

    [Process completed]
```

Comment: Every time I attempt to start up terminal, I see this error screen and I am not able to input any commands. Im sure its due to a tampered bash file but I do not know how to check for it without terminal, let alone restore it. Please help!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  You can use the Finder to locate the file by using the search option or using Spotlight. After finding the file you can try to edit it with TextEdit on your Mac.

Comment: I dont know which files are causing this error screen.

Comment: Is this a normal error message? Ive only started seeing this once I started using terminal to compile text editors instead of using IDEs. Now I cant even input any commands. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Well if you think its a bash file you should check the files .bashrc and .bash_profile. Both of these files are in your user directory (Folder) and can be viewed with an editor.

Comment: Be sure hidden files are visible. See hidden files on Mac via Finder. In Finder, open up your Macintosh HD folder. Press Command+Shift+Dot. Your hidden files will become visible. Repeat step 2 to hide them again!

Comment: Have you tried using iTerm instead of Terminal. Its a better Terminal emulator. That would tell you if its a Terminal problem or a bash problem.  Download iTerm 2 from https://www.iterm2.com.  Install it on your mac and use it like you do Terminal.

Comment: I downloaded iterm2 but im getting the same error message as in terminal.

Comment: -bash EO: command not found
-bash cl: command not found

Comment: Wait! just saw I am missing .bashrc! how do I restore this??

Comment: The `~/.bashrc` file does not exist by default, so if it's missing, it's no big deal.